# Getting formula while reading cell data in OpenPyXL

Tags: python, python-3.5, openpyxl

I want to update value in excel and get new updated value of output cell in excel using OpenPyXL in python 3

Below is code

```
import openpyxl
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('sheet.xlsx')

sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print (sheet['D2'].value)
sheet['A2'] =  3
print (sheet['D2'])
xfile.save('sheet.xlsx')
```

and below is sample data in excel :
[Image of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqhSJ.png)

and below is output I am getting

```
python3 xl.py
=SUM(A2:C2)
<Cell 'Sheet1'.D2>
```

How can I get value of this cell as calculated after application of formula (=SUM(A2:C2) in this case ).

Comment: You can't, `openpyxl` is **not** Excel! Read [A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/).

Comment: Any other library for that to read value from excel not formula?

Comment: To clarify, you can read Values from a Formula Cell but this doesn't recalculate the Value if you change a referenced Cells Value. Use one integrated in Excel like `win32com.client` or `xlwings`.

Comment: 'xlwings' only works for windows and OSX any similar library for ubuntu/linux?

Comment: It seems that you aren't want or can't use Excel therefore don't hassle with `xlsx` read about `pandas`, do your calculation and export back to `xlsx`.